# Coverage of the 99% Confidence Interval of a Binomial Proportion

Tags: python, r, statistics, rpy2

I have an rpy2 script that gives me the coverage of the 95% confidence interval:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
binom = importr('binom')
from rpy2 import robjects

robjects.r('''library(binom)
p = seq(0,1,.01)
coverage = binom.coverage(p, 10, method="bayes", type = "central")$coverage
''')
```

I'd like to get the coverage of the 99% confidence interval please

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this way?

```
robjects.r('''library(binom)
p = seq(0,1,.01)
coverage = binom.coverage(p, 10, conf.level = 0.99, 
method="bayes", type = "central")$coverage
''')
```

See [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/binom/versions/1.1-1/topics/binom.coverage).